# Not able to retrieve an item from localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

When I reload my page, I am trying unsuccessfully to retrieve some values in localStorage from a previous visit to the page. The item I'm trying to retrieve is not particularly complex: five keys with string values and one key that is an array of several objects.

```
let temp;
console.log('reading localStorage');
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(quizId))); // correct, shows what is in localStorage
temp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(quizId));
console.log('reading temp');
console.log(temp); // has different values from what is in localStorage
```

Anyone have any ideas why the contents of the two console.logs might be different? (I've tried using a timeout between the calls, and using Object.assign() but they didn't make any difference to the output.)

EDITS:
This is six lines of consecutive code, from a larger file, so I'm not changing anything between these lines.

The object to be retrieved from localStorage is of the form:

```
quizId = {
uname: 'dmorg',
uID: 1234,
currentView: "Q1",
thisQuiz: 
  [
    null, // to line up indices with question numbers
    [ // question 1
      null,
      // question 1 part 1
      {isAnswered: false, correctSoln: 1.234, userInput: 2.34, ...}
      // question 1 part 2
      {isAnswered: true, correctSoln: 3.41, userInput: 3.41, ...}
      ...
    ],
    [ // question 2
     ...
  ];
}; // end quizId
```

`temp` contains keys/values from initializing the page before any inputs from users, e.g. isAnswered is still set to false even when true in localStorage, userInput is 0 even when userInput is 3.41 in localStorage.

What confuses me is that I am setting localStorage correctly but cannot retrieve the current item from localStorage when the page is refreshed or revisited.

Corrected typo noticed by @Alex; this is code I typed here to give an indication of the object being stored.

@Leonardo, I have tried to reproduce it in CodePen but cannot access localStorage that way. Will start a new minimum working example and start to reintroduce functionality...

TIA

Comment: Can u please share more inputs, like o/p and other details. thanks

Comment: Is this complete code? It's not likely that your localStorage changes between two calls. Does `temp` contains data from localStorage or something else?

Comment: In your example, the quizId object is not valid because of the = in it.

Comment: I'd copy pasted your code to my local, but I couldn't reproduce the result you said